# weird error, trying to create a generic linked list class in java

Tags: java, generics, syntax-error

```
public class GenericLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Cloneable {

GenericListNode<T> head;

/**
 * inserts a new node containing the data toAdd at the given index.
 * @param index
 * @param toAdd
 */
public <T> void add (int index, T toAdd) {
    GenericListNode<T> node = new GenericListNode<T>((T) toAdd);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = node;
    } else {

    }

}
```

This is the code I have and for some reason it has a problem with me doing

```
head = node;
```

It says:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from GenericListNode<T> to GenericListNode <T extends Comparable<T>>
```

It suggests Casting node to be

```
head = (GenericListNode<T>) node;
```

But it still gives me the error.

Comment: What do you think the `T` in `public <T> void add` does?

Comment: how does your class GenericListNode look

Answer (score 4):

In this declaration

```
public <T> void add
```

you are defining a new type called `T` that is completely independent from the `T` defined at the class level. That's the notation for declaring a generic method.

Since the two types don't have the same bounds, they are not compatible and one cannot be converted to the other.

Get rid of that generic declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Don't redefine `T` in your method:

```
public void add (int index, T toAdd) {
    GenericListNode<T> node = new GenericListNode<T>((T) toAdd);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = node;
    } else {

    }
}
```

`T` is already defined at "class-level", if you add it again on the method you are hiding the class-level one, thus you have two different types called `T`.

Answer (score 2):

You are re-defining (read: shadowing) the generic definition of `T`. Just drop it from the method definition and you should be fine:

```
public class GenericLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Cloneable {

    GenericListNode<T> head;

    /**
     * inserts a new node containing the data toAdd at the given index.
     * @param index
     * @param toAdd
     */
    public void add (int index, T toAdd) {
        GenericListNode<T> node = new GenericListNode<T>(toAdd);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = node;
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```